# How to check the sub string is exists or not in main string

Tags: php

Is there any way to check the sub string is exists in main string or not. If exits, no need any another action. If not exists, I want to add some another string to main string.

For an example:

```
$a = 'Hello world';
$b = 'Hello';
```

I want to check the `$b` is exists in `$a` or not. If exists, i am sending that variable to database. If not exists, I want to use `str_replace('Hello', $b.'World', $b)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (strpos($a, $b) !== false) {
    // $b is in $a
} else {
    // $b is not in $a
    str_replace('Hello', $b . 'World', $b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`strpos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

It returns `FALSE` if the substring is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [strpos function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

remember to use === instead of ==